# Pivot SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot-table

I have a table with a column "date" and "name".
Here you can find a sample of my table: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eddede/1

What I need to do is to count how many rows a person has for every year. If the person doesn't have a value in year X, you must see 0. The order of the names must be on total count of current year DESC, so at the moment: 2014.

I can count for every year/name, but not sure I need this for the pivot table: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eddede/3

I would like that the result should look like this:

```
NAME        2012    2013    2014   TOTAL
Person B      2       2       2      6
Person C      0       1       2      3
Person A      4       3       1      8
```

I've tried, but I get something like this (So I don't post the wrong SQL-query...)

```
2012    2013    2014
  6       6       5
```

Comment: If you are in MySQL you better add it in the tags.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the result using an aggregate function with some conditional logic like a `CASE` expression:

```
select 
  name,
  sum(case when year(date) = 2012 then 1 else 0 end) [2012],
  sum(case when year(date) = 2013 then 1 else 0 end) [2013],
  sum(case when year(date) = 2014 then 1 else 0 end) [2014],
  count(*) Total
from list
group by name;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7b330/1)

Now, if the year values are unknown, then you will need to use dynamic SQL. This creates a string of the SQL that you need to execute:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @orderby nvarchar(max)

select @cols 
  = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(year(date)) 
           from list
           group by year(date)
           order by year(date)
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

select @orderby = 'ORDER BY ['+cast(year(getdate()) as varchar(4)) + '] desc'

set @query = 'SELECT name, ' + @cols + ', Total
            from 
            (
                select name, year(date) dt,
                   count(*) over(partition by name) Total
                from list
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                count(dt)
                for dt in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '+ @orderby


exec sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7b330/8)

Comment: And how can I order this dynamic query on the current year? Because now Person A is first, and it should be B (or C in my (bad) example)

Comment: @endeka You want the current year to be displayed as the first column, I'm not exactly sure what you are asking?

Comment: No, look at my post for an example of the result. In your demo it's: person A, person B, Person C; But I need to order by the count in column of current year (at the moment: 2014) Suppose we are in 2015, then I need to order on the count in 2015. Do you understand it now? And in the real table, I only need the top-10 users of the current year.

Comment: @endeka See my edit, I created another variable that holds the order by and then just concatenated that order by to the sql string.

Comment: @bluefeet,tnx this is the result I need.But when I run the code I get this error (in Micr. SQL Server Management Studio): Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Must declare the scalar variable "@sql".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Must declare the scalar variable "@OrderBy".
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 6
'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 15
'NOW' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 19
Must declare the scalar variable "@sql".
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 26
Incorrect syntax near 'PREPARE'.

Comment: We are on SQL Server 2008 R2, CONCAT is not possible here?

Comment: @endeka Ah, well your SQL Fiddle demo was MySQL so everyone guessed that was the database you were using.  I've updated the answer to SQL Server.

Comment: Sorry, it was the first time I used SQL Fiddle. Didn't know I could change it. Tnx, this is working!

Comment: @bluefeet, I need to add some more information. If you have the time to help me, this is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25784437/extend-current-query-calculated-columns

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT  
  name,  
  SUM(if(year(date) = 2012, 1, 0)) AS '2012', 
  SUM(if(year(date) = 2013, 1, 0)) AS '2013', 
  SUM(if(year(date) = 2014, 1, 0)) AS '2014' 
FROM list 
GROUP BY name;
```

and with total :)

```
SELECT
  t.name,
  t.`2012`,
  t.`2013`,
  t.`2014`,
  t.`2012` + t.`2013` + t.`2014` as total
FROM
(
SELECT  
  name,  
  SUM(if(year(date) = 2012, 1, 0)) AS `2012`, 
  SUM(if(year(date) = 2013, 1, 0)) AS `2013`, 
  SUM(if(year(date) = 2014, 1, 0)) AS `2014`
FROM list 
GROUP BY name
) as t
```

Comment: You forgot the total... ;-)

Comment: Tnx for the reply. But the year can not be hardcoded, this is why I was looking for a solution with a pivot table...

Comment: As far as i know the columns for pivot tables have to be hard-coded ... if you need some dynamics in the pivot table you have to wrap the query creation in t-sql, php, c# etc.